# video from node to v4l2

Tags: ros, video, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I need to pass a video stream from the ardrone_autonomy package's topic 'ardrone/front/image_raw' to a v4l2 (Video 4 Linux 2) virtual device dev/video0. Is there any package that could help me do this?
Thanks for the help!
andre_th

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203812/video-from-node-to-v4l2/) by [andre_th](https://answers.ros.org/users/21721/andre_th/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<del>I believe [gscam](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam) can do this. Anything gstreamer can access, `gscam` can publish.</del>

Right, that is the wrong direction.

---

But according to [umlaeute/v4l2loopback/README](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) gstreamer can be a 'feeder' for the virtual v4l loopback device.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andre_th](https://answers.ros.org/users/21721/andre_th/) on 2015-03-26**:
Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to use Gstreamer but so far I cannot make it work. Seems that is quite complicated to create a pipeline starting from images. I posted a new question on the forum: [ar-drone without camera](http://answers.ros.org/question/205951/ar-drone-without-camera/).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Later answered in [Can we publish Image topic from ROS to a virtual video device](http://answers.ros.org/question/215325/can-we-publish-image-topic-from-ros-to-a-virtual-video-device/)

I just tried [ros-virtual-cam](https://github.com/jgoppert/ros-virtual-cam) out on a jade/14.04 system, looked fine.

If you want to run the tests:

```
sudo pip install v4l2capture
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1